# How can i reduce an Arrow head type if statement with 3 different else`s?

Tags: java, if-statement, anti-patterns

im going to try to explain myself in the best way possible, i have a method that looks like this:

```
if(condition1)
    if(condition2) {
        if(condition3) {
                      //do something if the 3 conditions are met
        }
        else {
              //do something if condition 3 is NOT met      
        }   
    }
    else{
                //do something if condition 2 is NOT met
        }               
else{
        //do something if condition 1 is NOT met
}
```

I have been having trouble expanding and maintaining this code and i have seen ways to prevent this anti-pattern from happening but the solutions only focused on how to refactor the code so the if-blocks came out more clean, but i havent seen any solutions aiming to clean out diferent else blocks and even less solutions that focus on else-blocks which have diferent functionality.

I'd be glad if any of you could enlight me on how to tackle this problem. Looking forward to your responses and thank you in advance :).

Edit: i know there are a lot of ways to arreange these conditionals what im asking is the most correct way to do it so the code is a little easier to maintain

Comment: I'm not sure what "clean out different else blocks" or "focus on else-blocks which have diferent functionality" mean. Can you explain more?

Comment: Yeah of course, what i meant is that i had seen solutions that focus on reducing the number of if-blocks or arranging them in a more elegant way so the code is easier to follow and maintain but i hadnt seen any solutions focusing on reducing the number of else-blocks or simply making the arrangement more readable and elegant.

A lot of solutions simply dont care about what is in the else-blocks (obviusly because it is not relevant in their code) but in the code im proposing the else-blocks contain code that is not just the defaultFunction. I hope i have explained myself correcly this time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It heavily depends on the type of conditions. Without further knowledge of the code logic, you could look at early returns, which could look something like this:

```py
if (not condition1) {
    //do something if condition 1 is NOT met

    return; //only required if language does not support else if
}
else if (not condition2) {
    //do something if condition 2 is NOT met

    return; //only required if language does not support else if
}
else if (not condition3) {
    //do something if condition 3 is NOT met

    return; //only required if language does not support else if
}
else {
    //do something if all three conditions are met
    
    return;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to omit the return statements since there is no fall-through behavior with the if-else blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Using early returns, you can simplify your logic to this:

```
 if (!condition1) {
    //do something if condition 1 is NOT met
    return;
 }
 
 if (!condition2) {
    //do something if condition 2 is NOT met
    return;
 }
 
 if(condition3) {
    //do something if the 3 conditions are met
 } else {
    //do something if condition 3 is NOT met      
 }
```

Comment: You don't even need early return for this, chaining if .. else if .. else if ... would also work.